# DSHOT receiver implementation on STM32F3

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm writing some code to implement the DSHOT protocol which is used to control Electronic Speed Controls (ESCs) that drive brushless DC motors.  I'm using the ST Micro Nucleo32 F303K8 dev board for development, but ultimately this code will go into a custom ESC I'm working on.  My development approach involves two of these boards, one will be a transmitter (source), and the other will be a receiver (sink).  That way I have control over both sides for bench testing.

I've managed to write a DSHOT transmitter using two timer channels and a DMA controller to program the bit widths for each frame.  This seems to be the typical approach that people have been using, and its working fine for me.  I have a pot that gets read by the ADC, and the appropriate value gets sent out the DSHOT frame.  This runs very fast with almost no CPU overhead, and I can send frames at up to 600 kbs (DSHOT600).

Now I'm trying to write a DSHOT receiver.  I used a similar approach with two timer channels configured to measure a pulse width, and a DMA channel to gather the results of the entire frame. This uses very little CPU overhead, and relies on DMA to capture the bits.  However, I have found that this approach is slow, and I'm not getting the performance needed to keep up with the bits.  My timer interrupt gets out of sync within just 3 or 4 bits, and starts dropping them.  The slowest DSHOT rate is 150 kbs, but I can't even keep up with that.  If I turn the transmitter down to 50 kbs (DSHOT50?) then I'm able to keep up with the bits on the receiver and I don't lose any, but this is way too slow.

I know there are hobby grade ESCs on the market that can receive DSHOT300, DSHOT600, and even DSHOT1200.  The majority of these are based on an STM32 of some flavor.  Is there a different approach I should take to receive bits at a faster rate?  The little Nucleo32 maxes out at 64 MHz.  Do I just need a different MCU that I can crank up the clock speed?

For reference, the Flyduino KISS ESC 24A Race Edition has a 48 MHz STM32, and I believe it can receive DSHOT600.  This is astonishing to me, and tells me I'm taking the wrong approach.
Help!  How can I receive my DSHOT bits faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I figured out the answer to my own question.  It turns out that I was using the input capture interrupt to drive some debug LEDs so that I could "watch" what was going on, and the interrupt routines take too much time.  Even toggling an LED inside the ISR requires too much context switching and eats up valuable microseconds.

I turned off the input capture interrupt and just let the DMA do its thing.  Using the standard approach for using input capture to measure a pulse width, each bit width gets captured by the DMA controller and stored in memory, then when the entire frame is finished I get one "capture complete" interrupt so I can go decode the bits.

I'm currently passing valid traffic at DSHOT150, and it looks like I should have enough overhead to go up to DSHOT600.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I had to look up DSHOT :-). It's a protocol very similar to the WS2812 RGB LEDs. A bit consists of some high time, some low time and after 16bits are sent, a reset of at least 2us occurs. So that outlines what we need to account for.

The good thing is, each bit will start with a high time so this is what we will need to capture, then we will need to capture the high-to-low transition and that's about it. Restart the state machine if there wasn't a transition for longer than 2us.

A total bit length is 1.67us, if you're running at 64 MHz that means you have roughly 100 processor cycles for each bit. It doesn't sound impossible but you'll need to take good care of timing, especially since the handling of interrupts also uses some CPU cycles.

What I'd do for a first run is (just a general guideline):

- Setup a timer ("signal timer") to trigger the low-to-high transition and the high-to-low transition. Ensure that this timer runs at maximum frequency
- Setup a second timer ("timeout timer") for a 2us delay, if such a delay occurs, an interrupt is triggered and your state machine is reset
- If the signal timer catches a signal, get the count, check if it is above or below some limit (935ns should be a good limit) and add that bit to some array; reset the timeout timer to its max value so your statemachine is not reset
- Once you have received 16bits, perform the calculations you need to perform

As I said, that's just a first guesstimate .. nothing more.

And one quick note: Generating an output stream of data can be easily done via the SPI DMA transfer.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  It seems that even the timer interrupts take too much time to keep up with the bits.  I added an answer with some details, the solution involves using strictly DMA with no interrupts until the frame is complete.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the difference is ... The timer solution would be 2 interrupts (or 3?) per cycle, the DMA is probably one. Anyway, great you were able to handle it. I also prefer DMA transfers when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your own question, but there is still something to add. You mention that you use **two** timer channels both for TX and RX. You can really do the same thing with just one channel. Take a look at my BLDC motor control firmware that runs on BlHeli_32 ESCs as a reference:

https://github.com/neoxic/ESCape32

It supports bidirectional DSHOT 300/600. It receives and transmits on the same line using the same **single** timer channel. Moreover, it properly syncs/resyncs with incoming DSHOT frames which you probably would want to also have since it's not enough to just start DMA capture at a random point in time - you don't want to start capturing in the middle of a frame. Similarly, if RX goes out of sync due to spurious spikes, you would want to resync instead of proceeding with invalid out-of-sync frames.

In a nutshell, during RX the timer is configured in slave mode and resets on any edge while input capture triggers on falling edge (or rising edge for bidirectional DSHOT which is inverted). This allows to have sixteen clean pulse widths in the buffer upon DMA TC. During TX, slave mode is disabled, and the timer channel is switched to output in PWM mode. `TIM_CR2_CCDS` is also set to have DMA requests on UEV on the **same** DMA channel.

It's not a problem to implement support for DSHOT1200 or even DSHOT2400, but there's very little sense in doing so - bidirectional DSHOT demands a 25us delay after each RX/TX or TX/RX transition to let the remote party to reverse the line. So there's minimum 50us time that the line should be idle for between frames regardless of bitrate. There are other reasons due to which, for example, Betaflight dropped their DSHOT1200 support.